# List hovering messing with the whole nav div

Tags: hover, parent

im very very new to coding, like days in and theres this problem thats been driving me crazy.
Whenever i hover links or anything for some reason the whole parent of that list or other elements of the list kinda like twitch and change positions. Either way what can i do to make it so when i hover one element doesnt effect other elements.

```
<nav id="firstnav">
       <ul class="firstList">
          <li <a href="#">Purple Buzz</a></li>
          <li <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li <a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li <a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li <a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li <a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

#firstnav{
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.firstList{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;

}

.firstList{
margin-left: 35%;
}

li{
margin-right: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
}

li:hover{
  border: solid 1px purple;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you forgot the closing rafter `>` of the li.

The problem is the `padding` and the `border` added on hover.
**The `padding` and `hover` change the initial size of your html element** which causes the other elements to shift and the parent to grow in your case. To fix this, you can already set the `padding` initially. the `border` you set with a **transparent color**. then **on `hover`, you simply change the color of the border.**

like here below.

```css
#firstnav{
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.firstList{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;

}

.firstList{
margin-left: 35%;
}

li{
margin-right: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}

li:hover{
border-color: purple;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="firstnav">
       <ul class="firstList">
          <li> <a href="#">Purple Buzz</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: yes i noticed that after, but after running your code snippet the problem is still there, thanks though

Comment: please elaborate thanks ive been tucking my hair out

Comment: the probleme is the padding and the border added on hover.

Comment: i see, i wish i could show you what it looks like on my screen even after removing all padding and only having border bottom solid, it kinda likes move every other li on the left and it looks like it expands the whole nav

Comment: i have edited the post you can check the suggestion if it is right for you.

Comment: yep its how i imagined it, can you tell me what caused it?

Comment: The problem is the padding and the border added on hover.
The padding and hover change the initial size of your html element which causes the other elements to shift and the parent to grow. To fix this, you can already set the padding initially. the border you set with a transparent color. then on hover, you simply change the color of the border.